# PHP Array results in HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

I am trying to Array results from a MYSQL database into a html table, however when i do this, it seems to be showing one item per row (1 column)

here is my code

```
<?php 

$catagory=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","cl49-XXX","XXX");
if (!$con) 
  {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

mysql_select_db("cl49-XXX", $con)or die( "Unable to select database");

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE catagory  = '$catagory' ")or die('You need enter a catagoryE ' );
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $prodname=$row['prodname'];
  $prodID=$row['prodID'];
  echo"
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td>
  <b>$prodname </b><br>
  Product ID: $prodID<br /> 
 <img src='userpics/$prodID.jpg' height='200' width='200'></td></table> ";
}
?>
```

I am wanting a table with 3 columns, not 1?

Comment: If you create a new `<table>` for each record, then you're going to get a new table for each record.

Comment: @Stephen Alright. If you create a new `<table>` *and `<td>`* for each record...

Comment: It really doesn't matter if it's a new table for each record, that's not in question. "I am wanting a table with 3 columns, not 1?" -- We're talking columns not tables. If however we were talking tables, it'd be a straight forward, move the table tags outside of the loop.

Comment: I have managed to show all results in the table now, however the columns just go on and on, how do i limit this to 3 or 4?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably create 3 columns then.

You're only creating 1 column, your code slightly cleaned up:

```
 <table>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <b>$prodname </b><br>Product ID: $prodID<br/><img src='userpics/$prodID.jpg' height='200' width='200'>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

How about creating 3?

```
     <table>
      <tr>
        <td>This is a column</td>
        <td>This is a column</td> 
        <td>This is a column</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
```

Comment: Now it's ok. Previous version was not.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `while` loop with this

```
?>
<table>
    <?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $prodname = $row['prodname'];
        $prodID = $row['prodID'];
        echo "
        <tr>
            <td><b>$prodname </b></td>
            <td>Product ID: $prodID</td>
            <td><img src='userpics/$prodID.jpg' height='200' width='200'></td>
        </tr>";
    }
    ?>
<table>
```

Then read up on how html tables work

**Update**
To do what you want is a very odd way to use a table, however if that's what you want, something like this should work;

```
?>
<table>
    <?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($result); $i++)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        $prodname = $row['prodname'];
        $prodID = $row['prodID'];
        if ($i % 3 == 0) {
            echo "<tr>";
        }
        echo "
        <td>
            <b>$prodname </b><br />
            Product ID: $prodID<br />
            <img src='userpics/$prodID.jpg' height='200' width='200'>
        </td>";

        if (($i + 1) % 3 == 0 || ($i + 1) == mysql_num_rows($result)) {
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
    ?>
<table>
```

This should produce 3 columns per row, if you want more, change `$i % 3 == 0` to `$i % 4 == 0` in the two occurences

Comment: I have managed to show all results in the table now, however the columns just go on and on, how do i limit this to 3 or 4?

Comment: The code above will show each row with 3 columns. Make sure you've copied it correctly.

Comment: Sorry, in each `<td>` there is the prod name, prod id and image (all in the same cell) so for one product it looks like this `<td>
  <b>$prodname </b><br />
  Product ID: $prodID<br /> 
  <img src='userpics/$prodID.jpg' height='200' width='200'></td>`

Comment: So you want a table that contains 3-4 columns, each to have those 3 bits of information. Then start a new row again with 3-4 columns etc...?

Comment: im not sure how to do it?

Comment: I have changed the code to your updates above, now the table is showing 1 column on the first row, then 3, then 1 then 3 then 1 etc???

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit code as below:

```
  <table>
     <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Img</th>
   </tr>
 <?php 
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     $prodname=$row['prodname'];
      $prodID=$row['prodID'];
     echo"
  <tr>
      <td>$prodname </td>
      <td> $prodID</td> 
     <td><img src='userpics/$prodID.jpg' height='200' width='200'>
      </td></tr> ";
 }?>
```

Comment: is there a way to only have 3 columns?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create three columns in PHP echo:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<b>$prodname</b></td>
<td>Product ID: $prodID</td> 
<td><img src='userpics/$prodID.jpg' height='200' width='200'></td>
</table>
```